# Saving vector of objects using SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl

Im learning SDL2 and now im trying to save a game ranking into a .bin file. I have placed the ranking data into a vector. But im unable to save the data. Perhabs it has to do with file size, but im unable to solve that. This is the code that im using now:

```
class Player {
 private:
  std::string name, faction, dific;
  int points;
 public:
  Player() {};
  virtual ~Player() {};
  void addName(std::string s);
  void addFacti(std::string s);
  void addDific(std::string s);
  void addPoint(int p);
  std::string getName() const;
  std::string getFacti() const;
  std::string getDific() const;
  int getPoint() const;
  bool operator>(const Player& p) const;
};

Player p1; Player p2;//just two examples

//add properties to each object

std::vector<Player>classi;
classi.push_back(p1); classi.push_back(p2);
std::sort(classi.begin(), classi.end(), std::greater<Player>());

//load file
SDL_RWops* rankfile = SDL_RWFromFile("ranking.bin", "r+b");
for (int i = 0; i < classi.size(); ++i) { SDL_RWread(rankfile, &classi[i], sizeof(Player), 1); }
SDL_RWclose(rankfile);

//im able to render the objects

//save file - but it doesnt save anything
rankfile = SDL_RWFromFile("ranking.bin", "w+b");
for (int i = 0; i < classi.size(); ++i) { SDL_RWwrite(rankfile, &classi[i], sizeof(Player), 1); }
SDL_RWclose(rankfile);
```

Comment: In memory a `std::string` is basically a few pointers. The data is stored on the heap somewhere outside the object. Long story short, you can't save and load them that way, you need to serialize the data. One way is to write the length and then the string data to save and read the length, resize the string, then read the data to load. This is not necessarily your current problem, but if you solve that you're gonna hit this.

Comment: One other thing worth noting. You don't have any error checking in this code. You should be checking the `rankfile` pointer to make sure it is not NULL and checking the return value from the read and write functions.

Comment: @Retired Ninja In order to do that, will i need a library?

Comment: There are libraries like boost serialization and protobuf, but I wouldn't use them for a simple object like what you've shown unless I was already using them for another reason and I just wanted to be consistent. I'd just make a simple function something like `bool writeString(std::fstream& out, const std::string& s) { size_t sz = s.size(); out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sz), sizeof(sz)); out.write(s.data(), s.size()); }` and a `readString()` that mirrors it. Add error checking and return success or failure. You could use the SDL functions to read/write also, but I prefer `fstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how I might serialize a struct containing `std::string` to/from binary. It doesn't use the SDL functions because I don't use SDL but it wouldn't be difficult to modify if desired.

You may have a different problem since you say your file is empty, and I am concerned that you try and read the file before you write it, but you could try something like this and see if it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
std::ostream &writeBinary(std::ostream &f, T data)
{
    return f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data), sizeof(data));
}

std::ostream &writeBinary(std::ostream &f, const std::string &str)
{
    // If file size is a concern you might use a smaller type like uint16_t.
    // Just make sure to mirror the change in readBinary.
    std::string::size_type sz = str.size();
    if (f)
    {
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sz), sizeof(sz));
    }
    if (f)
    {
        f.write(str.data(), str.size());
    }
    return f;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream &readBinary(std::istream &f, T &data)
{
    if (f)
    {
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data), sizeof(data));
    }
    return f;
}

std::istream &readBinary(std::istream &f, std::string &str)
{
    std::string::size_type sz = 0;
    if (f)
    {
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sz), sizeof(sz));
    }
    if (f)
    {
        str.resize(sz);
        f.read(str.data(), sz);
    }
    return f;
}

struct Thing
{
    std::string shortString;
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string longString;

    Thing()
        : i(99)
        , d(99.99)
    {    }

    bool operator==(const Thing &rhs) const
    {
        return std::tie(shortString, i, d, longString)
            == std::tie(rhs.shortString, rhs.i, rhs.d, rhs.longString);
    }

    bool write(std::ofstream &f)
    {
        if (!writeBinary(f, shortString))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!writeBinary(f, i))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!writeBinary(f, d))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!writeBinary(f, longString))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool read(std::ifstream &f)
    {
        if (!readBinary(f, shortString))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!readBinary(f, i))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!readBinary(f, d))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!readBinary(f, longString))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Thing &t)
{
    return o << "'" << t.shortString << "'" << ", "
        << t.i << ", " << t.d << ", "
        << "'" << t.longString << "'";
}

int main()
{
    Thing t1;
    // Shorter string to hopefully fit in any short string optimization buffer in the string. 
    t1.shortString = "Short";
    t1.longString = "Long string that should be long enough to not fit in the SSO buffer.";
    t1.i = 42;
    t1.d = 42.42;

    std::cout << "t1 Before Write: " << t1 << "\n";
    std::ofstream out("thing.bin", std::ios::binary);
    if (!t1.write(out))
    {
        std::cout << "Error writing t1!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    out.close();
    std::cout << "t1 After Write: " << t1 << "\n";

    Thing t2;
    std::cout << "t2 Before Read: " << t2 << "\n";
    std::ifstream in("thing.bin", std::ios::binary);
    if (!t2.read(in))
    {
        std::cout << "Error reading t2!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    in.close();
    std::cout << "t2 After Read: " << t2 << "\n";

    std::cout << "t1 == t2: " << std::boolalpha << (t1 == t2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have adapted your code to the Player class. But how can i serialize a vector of players? i have searched for examples, but i havent been able to get one that writes/read something like that.

Comment: It depends. If your file will only include player data then you could just use a loop to write each one after the other and read them back with something like `Player p; while(p.read(in)) { vector.push_back(p); }` If you have a file with multiple types of data you can write a header describing the type and count of objects and use that to decide how to read it back.

Comment: Thanks. This, together with the original answer, solves the problem of saving a vector. I dont even have to use the SDL functions.