# A simple c++ binary file working but why I cannot exit the program with enter?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I found this example from here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reading-and-writing-binary-file-in-c-cplusplus

I copy that and put into my Visual Studio 2019. The result is fine but I cannot exit the program with Enter. I have to press ESC wait for it before the program exit itself with "exited with code -1073741819"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Student {
    int roll_no;
    string name;
};
int main() {
    ofstream wf("student.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!wf) {
        cout << "Cannot open file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    Student wstu[3];
    wstu[0].roll_no = 1;
    wstu[0].name = "Ram";
    wstu[1].roll_no = 2;
    wstu[1].name = "Shyam";
    wstu[2].roll_no = 3;
    wstu[2].name = "Madhu";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        wf.write((char*)&wstu[i], sizeof(Student));
    wf.close();
    if (!wf.good()) {
        cout << "Error occurred at writing time!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    ifstream rf("student.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!rf) {
        cout << "Cannot open file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    Student rstu[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        rf.read((char*)&rstu[i], sizeof(Student));
    rf.close();
    if (!rf.good()) {
        cout << "Error occurred at reading time!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Student's Details:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Roll No: " << wstu[i].roll_no << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << wstu[i].name << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't write and read a struct with a `std::string` directly as binary. You need to properly serialize it. A simple method is to write the length followed by the data and to read it you read the length, resize the destination string and read the data into it. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933890/920069

Comment: Unrelated: why do you use `ios::out` for `std::ifstream`?

Answer (score 0):

Above comment are really appreciable and must be considered.
One another method would be defining name as character pointer like:

```
char *name;
```