# Can C++ parse an std::list of objects from the same class but are of different sizes?

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to store a list of objects into a binary file. The objects' class is Order:

```
class Order{
private:
    string name;
    string address;
    int number_of_tickets;
public:
    bool operator == (const Order& o) const {
        return name == o.getName() && address == o.getAddress() && number_of_tickets == o.getTickets();
    }

    bool operator != (const Order& o) const {
        return !operator==(o);
    }

    Order(string n, string a, int num){
        this->name = n;
        this->address = a;
        this->number_of_tickets = num;
    }

    Order copy() const{
        return Order(this->name, this->address, this->number_of_tickets);
    }

    void display() const{
        cout << getName() << " " << getAddress() << " " << getTickets() << endl;
    }
    string getName() const{
        return name;
    }
    string getAddress() const{
        return address;
    }
    int getTickets() const{
        return number_of_tickets;
    }
};
```

I use these functions I've made to save and load my list of objects:

```
void save(list<Order>& l){
    fstream save;
    save.open("orders.list", ios::out | ios::binary);
    long size = sizeof(l);
    save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    cout << endl << "Size is = " << size << endl; 
    save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&l), size);
    cout << "Orders Saved!\n";
}
void load(list<Order>& l){
    fstream load;
    load.open("orders.list", ios::in | ios::binary);
    long size;
    load.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    cout << endl << "Size is = " << size << endl; 
    load.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&l), size);
    cout << "Orders Loaded!\n";
```

When I try to output the elements of the list after saving and loading using a range based loop, I get a segmentation fault. This is the function I use to output the object:

```
void displayAll(list<Order>& l){
    cout << "Displayed All Orders!\n";
    if(l.empty()){
        cout << "No Orders" << endl;
    }else{
        for(const auto& order : l){
             order.display();
        }
    }
}
```

While the code is running, I am able to save and extract all the elements in the loop using the displayAll(list&) function.

```
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
1
Enter Name: Migs
Enter Address: Felipe
Enter Number of Tickets: 2
Order Added!
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
1
Enter Name: Mecky
Enter Address: Lymurst
Enter Number of Tickets: 1
Order Added!
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
4
Displayed All Orders!
Migs Felipe 2
Mecky Lymurst 1
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
```

But when I try to retrive the data after saving, I get a segmentation fault when trying to output the elements after loading:

```
4
Displayed All Orders!
Migs Felipe 2
Mecky Lymurst 1
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
5

Size is = 24
Orders Saved!
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
7
mechy88@LAPTOP-SJIPE7SP:/mnt/c/Users/Miguel/Desktop/ADNU-CS-repo/CSDC102_E3$ ./a.out
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
4
Displayed All Orders!
No Orders
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
6

Size is = 24
Orders Loaded!
Choose a command
        1. Add an order
        2. Cancel an order
        3. Search an order
        4. Display all orders
        5. Save orders
        6. Load saved orders
        7. Close Program
4
Displayed All Orders!
Segmentation fault
mechy88@LAPTOP-SJIPE7SP:/mnt/c/Users/Miguel/Desktop/ADNU-CS-repo/CSDC102_E3$
```

It seems to me like the the program is able to load and store the list of Order objects into the list variable, but is having problems handling the data after extracting. I'm not sure where to move from here, or what to try next.

Here again. I've revised my code after taking in your suggestions and implementing the linked resource from retired ninja. But I seem to be running into some problems when compiling. Here's the error:

mechy88@LAPTOP-SJIPE7SP:/mnt/c/Users/Miguel/Desktop/ADNU-CS-repo/CSDC102_E3$ g++ PAJARILLO_E3.cpp
PAJARILLO_E3.cpp: In function ‘void load(std::__cxx11::list&)’:
PAJARILLO_E3.cpp:215:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream::char_type*’ {aka ‘char*’} [-fpermissive]
215 |         load.read(name.data(), size_name);
|                   ~~~~~~~~~^~
|                            |
|                            const char*
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
from PAJARILLO_E3.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:486:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char; std::streamsize = long int]’
486 |       read(char_type* __s, streamsize __n);
|            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
PAJARILLO_E3.cpp:221:31: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream::char_type*’ {aka ‘char*’} [-fpermissive]
221 |         load.read(address.data(), size_address);
|                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
|                               |
|                               const char*
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
from PAJARILLO_E3.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:486:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char; std::streamsize = long int]’
486 |       read(char_type* __s, streamsize __n);
|            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~

Here's the revised save() and load() functions:

```
void save(list<Order>& l){

    fstream save;
    save.open("orders.list", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int size = l.size();
    save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));

    for(const auto& order : l){
        string name = order.getName();
        string::size_type size_name = name.length();
        save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size_name), sizeof(size_name));
        save.write(name.data(), size_name);

        string address = order.getAddress();
        string::size_type size_address = address.length();
        save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size_address), sizeof(size_address));
        save.write(address.data(), size_address);

        int tickets = order.getTickets();
        save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tickets), sizeof(tickets));
    }

}
void load(list<Order>& l){
    ifstream load;
    load.open("orders.list", ios::binary);
    int size;
    load.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        string name;
        string::size_type size_name;
        load.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size_name), sizeof(size_name));
        name.resize(size_name);
        load.read(name.data(), size_name);

        string address;
        string::size_type size_address;
        load.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size_address), sizeof(size_address));
        address.resize(size_address);
        load.read(address.data(), size_address);

        int tickets;
        load.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tickets), sizeof(tickets));

        l.push_back(Order(name, address, tickets));
    }

}
```

Comment: The size of all these objects is the same. The strings are not stored in the objects - only pointers to strings. When you save the pointers and load the pointers into a different program they don't work.

Comment: I assume this is `std::list`. `long size = sizeof(l);` is the size of the list object itself, typically a few pointers, not the data in the nodes. `save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&l), size);` is writing the actual list object to the file, not any of the data it contains in nodes. In order to do this properly you will need to serialize the list one node at a time. Since your objects contain `std::string` objects you will need to serialize those individually as well.

Comment: user253751 I see I see, thank you! I'll test that out. You're right, I did think the strings caused the objects to be different in size.

Comment: Retired Ninja I understand. Thank you! I'll try implementing your suggestion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925429/saving-vector-of-objects-using-sdl2/66933890#66933890 may help you get started.

Comment: @MiguelAndreRepatacodo -- The bottom line is that your current code cannot work.  You cannot write non-POD types like this.  You can't even write `std::string` like this -- the reason is simple.  The last argument is `sizeof()`, which is a compile-time value.  Regardless of how many objects, characters, etc., the `sizeof()` will be the same value.  Let's say that `sizeof(l)` is 40.  Let's say your list has 10000 items.  The `sizeof(l)` will still be 40.